# How does Precision and Scale work for Oracle's NUMBER data type?

Tags: oracle

If I have an ID field that is 7 characters long what do I set the scale and precision to? This is rather confusing. Or say a field of 10 characters for a phone number ... what is the S and P then?

Answer (score 2):

For a series of digits such as a phone number or Social Security Number, or Zip Code, or ISBN, consider what operations you will be carrying out on it.

Will you be:

1. adding them together, taking the average, representing them with variable numbers of decimal places, multiplying them, etc?
2. Or will you be checking the length, splitting them out into a pattern, needing to preserve any leading zero, extracting a set of characters (first three, last four), comparing them to a regular expression, etc?

If the former, then they are numbers and you should store them as an integer. If the latter then they are strings constrained to be composed only of certain characters, and you should store them as a string with an appropriate check constraint.

I think at the moment you're asking something like "what temperature should my aquarium water be held at to keep cats in it"? The answer, probably, is not to do it at all, as you'll end up bitten.

Answer (score 1):

For an ID, since you shouldn't need decimals, a precision of 7 and a scale of 0 would work in your case. For a phone number, you would use a varchar2 or something comparable, in which case a scale and precision wouldn't apply.

You mentioned "characters" for the ID, but I'm assuming it's numerical.

Documentation regarding scale and precision in Oracle can be found here... http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832

Specifically:

> ...you can also specify a precision (total number of digits) and scale (number of digits to the right of the decimal point)

Note though that precision and scale are optional and you may not even need to worry about them for something like an ID.

More examples can be found here... [What is the difference between precision and scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689369/what-is-the-difference-between-precision-and-scale-in-oracle)

Comment: Are you assuming the phone number would have non-numeric characters or the variable length of different countries numbers?