# NUMBER(12,0)'s meaning in "S_NO NUMBER(12,0) NOT NULL ENABLE PRIMARY KEY"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Can anyone clarify what datatype `NUMBER(12,0)` means in `S_NO NUMBER(12,0) NOT NULL ENABLE PRIMARY KEY`?

Please clarify each parameter (i.e. `12,0`).

Comment: Reading the fine manual - Database SQL Language Reference: [Data types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021) ?

Answer (score 2):

`NUMBER(12,0)` indicates a numeric data type with *precision* `12` and *scale* `0`.

A [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5689458/1810429) explains precision and scale further:

> Precision is the number of significant digits. Oracle guarantees the
>   portability of numbers with precision ranging from 1 to 38.
>
> Scale is the number of digits to the right (positive) or left
>   (negative) of the decimal point. The scale can range from -84 to 127.

Applying this explanation to your case, the maximum number that `NUMBER(12,0)` could store would be `999999999999` (i.e. 12 significant digits with no digits to the right or left of the decimal point).

There are many other supporting explanations of Oracle's numeric data types, precision, and scale online too, including a good [one from Oracle FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NUMBER).

Comment: are you able to clarify it or not?

Comment: ok what is diffrence between TIMESTAMP(6) and TIMESTAMP(4),TIMESTAMP(5)

Comment: @sam: Not to be rude, but **a)** a search goes a long way (e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006050), **b)** your comment adds a different question to your original question, and **c)** this is classic [help vampirism](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258206/1810429?stw=2) (not a good thing).

Comment: @J0e3gan - if the OP won't read the manual it's unlikely they'll read a piece  on StackOverflow etiquette. More's the pity.