# How to display two decimal points in python, when a number is perfectly divisible?

Tags: python, decimal, string-formatting, fixed-point

Currently I am trying to solve a problem, where I am supposed to print the answer upto two decimal points ***without rounding off***. I have used the below code for this purpose

```
import math
a=1.175                            #value of a after some division
print(math.floor(a*100)/100)
```

The output we get is:

```
1.17                              #Notice value which has two decimal points & not rounded
```

But the real problem starts when I try to print a number which is evenly divisible, after the decimal point only one zero is displayed. I have used the same code as above, but now

```
a=25/5                                   #Now a is perfectly divisible
print(math.floor(a*100)/100)
```

The output displayed now is

```
5.0                                      #Notice only one decimal place is printed
```

what must be done rectify this bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The division works and returns adequate precision in result.

So your problem is just about visualization or exactly:

- **string-representation** of floating-point numbers

### Formatting a decimal

You can use **string-formatting** for that.
For example in Python 3, use *f-strings*:

`twoFractionDigits = f"{result:.2f}"`

or `print(f"{result:.2f}")`

The trick does `.2f`, a string **formatting literal** or *format specifier* that represents a floating-point number (`f`) with two fractional digits after decimal-point (`.2`).

See also:

- [Fixed digits after decimal with f-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310254/fixed-digits-after-decimal-with-f-strings)
- [How to format a floating number to fixed width in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python/8885688#8885688)

Try on the Python-shell:

```py
Python 3.6.9 (default, Dec  8 2021, 21:08:43) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> a=1.175                            #value of a after some division
>>> result = math.floor(a*100)/100
>>> result
1.17
>>> print(result)
1.17
>>> a=25/5                                   #Now a is perfectly divisible
>>> result = math.floor(a*100)/100
>>> result
5.0
>>> print(result)
5.0
>>> print(f"{result:.2f}")
5.00
```

#### Formatting a decimal as percentage

Similar you can represent the ratio as percentage:
`print(f"{result:.2f} %")`

prints:

> 5.00 %

A formatting **shortcut for percentage** can be:
`print(f"{25/100:.2%}")`
Which converts the result of `25/100 == 0.25` to:

> 25.00%

Note: The formatting-literal `.2%` automatically converts from ratio to percentage with 2 digits after the decimal-point and adds the percent-symbol.

#### Formatting a decimal with specific *scale* (rounded or truncated ?)

Now the part without rounding-off, just truncation.
As example we can use the [*repeating decimal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal), e.g. `1/6` which needs to be either *rounded* or *truncated* (cut-off) after a fixed number of fractional digits - the *scale* (in contrast to *precision*).

```py
>>> print(f"{1/6:.2}")
0.17
>>> print(f"{1/6:.2%}")
16.67%
```

Note how the formatted string is not truncated (to `0.16`) but rounded (to `0.17`). Here the *scale* was specified inside formatting-literal as `2` (after the dot).

See also:

- [Truncate to three decimals in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595973/truncate-to-three-decimals-in-python)
- [How do I interpret precision and scale of a number in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377174/how-do-i-interpret-precision-and-scale-of-a-number-in-a-database)
- [What is the difference between precision and scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689369/what-is-the-difference-between-precision-and-scale)

#### Formatting many decimals in fixed width (leading spaces)

Another example is to print multiple decimals, like in a column as right-aligned, so you can easily compare them.

Then use string-formatting literal `6.2f` to add leading spaces (here a fixed-width of 6):

```
>>> print(f"{result:6.2f}")
  5.00
>>> print(f"{100/25*100:6.2f}")
400.00
>>> print(f"{25/100*100:6.2f}")
 25.00
```

#### See also

All the formatting-literals demonstrated here can also be applied using

- old-style *%-formatting* (also known as "Modulo string formatting") which was inherited from [`printf` method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) of C language. Benefit: This way is also compatible with Python before 3.6).
- new-style `.format` method on strings (introduced with Python 3)

See [theherk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70882763/5730279) which demonstrates those alternatives.

Learn more about string-formatting in Python:

- Real Python: [Python 3's f-Strings: An Improved String Formatting Syntax (Guide)](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)
- Real Python: [Python String Formatting Best Practices](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/)

Comment: @theherk, your answer is great and shows also __common issues with floating-points__. I focused on string-formatting in general using "For example" f-string's as a useful pattern.

Comment: I regretted saying anything. This is a comprehensive answer, and the important thing here is that good questions get good answers. You're out here doing the lord's work, posting answers, adding tags, editing what needs edited. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can find this recommendation in the official Python tutorial: [15. Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

> For more pleasant output, you may wish to use string formatting to produce a limited number of significant digits

```
print("%.2f" % 3.0)
3.00
```

or

```
format(3.0, ".2f")
'3.00'
```

Comment: A bit off-topic but curious to learn from you:  What are the benefits for referencing URLs as foot-notes like `[1]` to be listed at the end ? Is it re-usability (multiple cross-references can point to a single URL) ?

Comment: It is for 2 reasons, neither of which are important. You correctly point out one, as the same reference can be used many times. The other is that, no matter the length of the url, the readability of the document in markdown format is not hindered.

Comment: Wow thanks, that is __link formatting best-practice__ that needs to be shared ️ (if not here, then in SO-meta or [Help: Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), section "Links")

Comment: What % sign means in ```print("%.2f" % 3.0)``` line?

Comment: @michalroesler: It is the character that indicates a replacement in [string interpolation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting) (old-style).