# f-string with percent and fixed decimals?

Tags: python, f-string

I know that I can to the following. But is it possible to combine them to give me a percent with fixed decimal?

```py
>>> print(f'{0.123:%}')
12.300000%
>>> print(f'{0.123:.2f}')
0.12
```

But what I want is this output:

```
12.30%
```

Comment: `f'{0.123:.2%}'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display two decimal points in python, when a number is perfectly divisible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70882733/how-to-display-two-decimal-points-in-python-when-a-number-is-perfectly-divisibl)

Comment: @JeanotZubler Although it contains the answer, the title of the question is not obviously the same. I searched on stackoverflow for an answer before asking, but found nothing. I hope the clear title will help others with the same question.

Comment: The google search `python format percentage 2 decimal places` returns 2 blogs and quite a few StackOverflow posts where this is solved. Looking for f strings specifically gives slightly worse results, but still solvable from the first page of google.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify the number of decimal places before `%`:

```
>>> f'{0.123:.2%}' 
'12.30%'
```

Comment: Omg, I have tried so many compositions but not this. Thanks for that! It makes total sense...