# Oracle - NUMBER type declaration with scale greater than precision

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table with a few `NUMBER(precision, scale)` columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE num_test
(
    n1 NUMBER(1, 0),
    n2 NUMBER(2, 0),
    n3 NUMBER(2, 1),
    n4 NUMBER(3, 1),
    n5 NUMBER(3, 2),
    n6 NUMBER(4, 3),
    n7 NUMBER(5, 4),
    n8 NUMBER(6, 4),
    n9 NUMBER(6, 4),
    n10 NUMBER(10, 5),
    n11 NUMBER(10, 9)
);
```

Sample data:

[image]

**Question:**

Oracle allows specifying a number where the `scale` >= `precision`, i.e.

- `NUMBER(1, 5)`
- `NUMBER(5, 5)`

It seems that it should not possible to have a number where precision is 1 and scale is 5. What would be an example of such numbers?

**Related:**

- [What is the difference between precision and scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689369/what-is-the-difference-between-precision-and-scale)

Comment: `NUMBER(1,5)` stores a single digit of precision and 5 decimal places; so `-0.00009` to `+0.00009`. The linked question answers it and so does @dfundako's quote from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It's written pretty plainly in their data types documentation:

> Scale can be greater than precision, most commonly when e notation is used. When scale is greater than precision, the precision specifies the maximum number of significant digits to the right of the decimal point. For example, a column defined as NUMBER(4,5) requires a zero for the first digit after the decimal point and rounds all values past the fifth digit after the decimal point.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html

Comment: Can you provide a couple of examples for the definitions in the question?

Comment: @abc No. You should be able to come up with an example based on the documentation and your examples.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which literally states "What would be an example of such numbers?".

Comment: It does answer the question as it states "a column defined as NUMBER(4,5) requires a zero for the first digit after the decimal point and rounds all values past the fifth digit after the decimal point." which is clearly `0.0XXXX`